# cv::bilateralFilter segfaults on image from cv_bridge

Tags: kinect, opencv, cv-bridge, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS node that takes in a depth image and converts it to an openCV compatible format. However it doesn't seem to be compatible with all openCV functions.

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr bridge;
try
{
    bridge = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, "32FC1");
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to transform depth image.");
    return;
}
depthImage = bridge->image;
cv::Mat depthImageFiltered(480,640,CV_32F);
cv::bilateralFilter( depthImage, depthImageFiltered, -1, 0.45, 3.0 );
```

This produces a segmentation fault on the last line whereas

```
cv::blur( depthImage, depthImageFiltered, cv::Size(5,5));
```

works without error. I see no reason why these two should behave differently.
Weirder still, the bilateralFilter works fine with floating-point images loaded through cv::imread(). What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31890/cv::bilateralfilter-segfaults-on-image-from-cv_bridge/) by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 465 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently what seems to cause the error is the presence of NaN's in the image.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) with karma: 465 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0